# An interview with Paul Kasey, movement advisor of movie "28 Weeks Later", during which he is dressed as an infected

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, 28-weeks-later

There used to be a relatively short video on Youtube (about 3 minutes or less, I think), titled something like "28 weeks later - interview with the infected", which was kind of a featurette/behind the scenes for the movie *[28 Weeks Later (2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/28_Weeks_Later)*.

It was an interview with Paul Kasey, the movement advisor for the movie, in which he explained how he coordinated the movements of the infected in the movie to make it believable.

Some other relevant stuff I remember:

- Since Paul Kasey was wearing the full costume of an infected, he described that "it looks painful because it's meant to be painful" when you are infected.
- Paul also mentioned having played the role of an infected, before the video transitions to a scene of the movie, when an infected bursts into the sleeping room at the beginning of the movie.
- I think another part of the video talked about the guys training to growl and letting out all their anger. And someone commented that when you spend so much energy into being angry all the time, after you leave your work and go home, you are so tired/relieved that you are very calm and peaceful.
- One scene depicted Paul putting on/removing a red eye lens (which he was wearing during the entire duration of the interview).
- The video ended with a (kind of) jump scare, with Paul trying to scare us by appearing on screen.

During my search, I kept stumbling on a video titled *[28 Weeks Later: The Infected](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1182248/)* on Youtube, but although Paul Kasey does appear in that video, it's not the one I'm looking for.

Here's a screenshot of Paul as he appeared in the video I am looking for, as he introduced himself.

**Warning: possibly graphical content, since he's covered in fake blood, face covered with blood veins and all that.**

> [image: A screenshot of the aforementioned video. This was taken at the beginning, when Paul Kasey is introducing himself, while disguised as an infected from the movie. His eyes appear to be entirely bloody red, his white shirt is covered in blood, and he looks like he vomited blood. Some veins are also visible around his face, and it looks like he also has some injuries on the forehead and the left ear.]

Comment: In case of doubt: I'm looking for that video (or at least where it originally came from), since the video I initially saw on Youtube disappeared.

Comment: [28 Weeks Later - The Rage Returns](https://www.ign.com/videos/28-weeks-later-movies-the-rage-returns). Clearly not the correct video

Comment: [Code Red - The Making Of 28 Weeks Later - A Survival Film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgUB2WG66GU) - Clearly not the correct video

Comment: [28 Weeks Later - Getting Into The Action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYLfLY3mHSE) - Correct font again, but doesn't show Paul Kasey

Comment: [28 Weeks Later:The Infected](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2bbKQ7NndA) - Correct font, but doesn't show Paul Kasey

Comment: [The Making of 28 Weeks Later](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twidqI2dpWA) - Paul Kasey appears in the video at 15.26, but not in costume

Comment: @Valorum _"Wow. That is dedication."_ - Someone in 2017

Comment: [28 Weeks Later: The Deleted Scene Collection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eO3cd1yduBU) clearly not the correct video

Comment: [28 Weeks Later: The Aftermath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OvjAmAILxk) - Clearly not the correct video

Comment: I've made contact with Mr Kasey via email. Hopefully he can shed some light on this for us